# Write C array contain binary data to file

Tags: c, arrays, file, binary

C is one language I do not know :) and my question may be silly for most of you.
This array contain file (style.css), listed only part of it, question is how to write it to file? Using linux - slackware.

```
static const char data_style_css[] = {
0x20, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x25, 0x29, 0x3B, 0x62, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x64, 0x65, 0x72, 0x3A, 0x73,
0x6F, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x64, 0x20, 0x31, 0x70, 0x78, 0x20, 0x23, 0x32, 0x34, 0x37, 0x42, 0x45,
0x36, 0x3B, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x3A, 0x23, 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x3B, 0x66, 0x6F,
0x6E, 0x74, 0x2D, 0x73, 0x69, 0x7A, 0x65, 0x3A, 0x31, 0x33, 0x70, 0x78, 0x3B, 0x68, 0x65,
0x69, 0x67, 0x68, 0x74, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x30, 0x70, 0x78, 0x3B, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x2D,
0x68, 0x65, 0x69, 0x67, 0x68, 0x74, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x30, 0x70, 0x78, 0x3B, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78,
0x74, 0x2D, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x67, 0x6E, 0x3A, 0x63, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x3B,
0x77, 0x69, 0x64, 0x74, 0x68, 0x3A, 0x30, 0x7D, 0 };
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about reading some book about C, especially a chapter about input and output?

Comment: `fprintf(fp, "%s", data_style_css);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
static const char data_style_css[] = {
 0x20, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x25, 0x29, 0x3B, 0x62, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x64, 0x65, 0x72, 0x3A,    0x73,
 0x6F, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x64, 0x20, 0x31, 0x70, 0x78, 0x20, 0x23, 0x32, 0x34, 0x37, 0x42, 0x45,
 0x36, 0x3B, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x3A, 0x23, 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x3B, 0x66, 0x6F,
 0x6E, 0x74, 0x2D, 0x73, 0x69, 0x7A, 0x65, 0x3A, 0x31, 0x33, 0x70, 0x78, 0x3B, 0x68, 0x65,
 0x69, 0x67, 0x68, 0x74, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x30, 0x70, 0x78, 0x3B, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x2D,
 0x68, 0x65, 0x69, 0x67, 0x68, 0x74, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x30, 0x70, 0x78, 0x3B, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78,
 0x74, 0x2D, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x67, 0x6E, 0x3A, 0x63, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x3B,
 0x77, 0x69, 0x64, 0x74, 0x68, 0x3A, 0x30, 0x7D, 0 };

char ch='\0';
int i;
FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("MyStyle.css","w");//A new file will be created named mystyle.css (IMPORTANT!!!...if your computer already has a file of same name then it will be erased.)

    if(fp==NULL)//if file cannot be created fp will have NULL value.
    {
        printf("\nError..Cannot Create a mystyle.css");
        return 1;
    }

    for(i=0;data_style_css[i]!=0;i++)//will end when your array element will reach 0..(as i see your array is ended with 0,hence it will end)
    {
        ch=data_style_css[i];//reading each character from your array into variable ch

        fprintf(fp,"%c",data_style_css[i]);//writing each character from ch into file fp(mystyle.css)
    }
fclose(fp);
printf("\nFile Created Successfully..");
return 0;   
}
```

This program will work only when your array will end with 0(so i assume that you will make sure it does everytime). A file named MyStyle.css will be created on the path where you will execute this program.

All the contents of array will be written to file Mystyle.css, open and check to see output.

output which i got is:-

100%);border:solid 1px #247BE6;color:#FFF;font-size:13px;height:30px;line-height:30px;text-align:center;width:0}

I see that your .css file which is stored in array does not have new line characters. so out put is not clean.All the output is show in single line in a text file.You can optimize the above program to get clean readable text file.(other wise you would manually have to edit .css file to set all those css tags on new line)

You can optimize the for loop in this way:-

```
for(i=0;data_style_css[i]!=0;i++)//will end when your array element will reach 0..(as i see your array is ended with 0,hence it will end)
{
    ch=data_style_css[i];//reading each character from your array into variable ch

    if(ch=='{'||ch=='}')//when ch is '{' or '}' (As new block is started/ended on css print new line in file fp(Mystyle.cc)
        fprintf(fp,"%c",'\n');

    fprintf(fp,"%c",data_style_css[i]);//writing each character from ch into file fp(mystyle.css)

    if(ch==';')//when ch is ';' (As css tags end with semicolon the next tag should be on new line.Hence print newline on fp(Mystyle.css) )
        fprintf(fp,"%c",'\n');
}
```

With Above Optimization i get the following ***output(clean and readable)*** on Mystyle.css:-

100%);

border:solid 1px #247BE6;

color:#FFF;

font-size:13px;

height:30px;

line-height:30px;

text-align:center;

width:0

}

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answer, I give up on C , manage to do it with language that I understand - LUA will post the script as soon as site permit me to answer my own question. The output file is indeed without CR&LF char. That is not problem for the browsers.

Comment: you are welcome...:) and don't give up,by the way, how did you get that .css file into the array.?????

Answer (score 0):

Your array represents a standard null-terminated string. You can write it into a file using the standard C I/O library.

Here's a simple example:

```
FILE* f = fopen("output_file", "w");
if (f == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
}
else {
    fprintf(f, "%s", data_style_css);
    fclose(f);
}
```

This link will give you full details about these functions (and many more): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output

Answer (score 0):

I try some of C answer without success, so suggestion for reading some C book is the right. I manage to do what I want with program language that I understand - LUA here is the script:

```
all=""   
for i, v in ipairs(data_fail_html)  do all=all..string.char(v) end
        print (all)
```

Assume "data_fail_html" is the array contain binary data.

from linux dropbear shell:

```
lua script.lua >> data_fail.html
```

Thanks you all for your time